# Setting "Paravirtualization Interface" in Vagrantfile

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

VirtualBox 5 exposes a setting called ["Paravirtualization Interface"](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html#gimproviders) that can improve performance for some specific guest operating systems.

Is there a way to set this option in a `Vagrantfile`?

And in general: Is there documentation on how to set the acceleration settings via the Vagrantfile?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found it. `VBoxManage` (the VirtualBox CLI tool) has an optional argument called `--paravirtprovider`. You can add that to the `vb.customize` call:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.customize [
      "modifyvm", :id,
      "--memory", "1024",
      "--paravirtprovider", "kvm", # for linux guest
      "--cpus", "2"
    ]
  end
end
```

The other CPU settings are also available that way, `vb.customize` accepts the same argument as `VBoxManage`. Refer to `VboxManage --help` to get a list of all the options.

Answer (score 2):

My Vagrantfile did not have a vb.customize section (maybe the accepted answer uses older format (?)).
Based on https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/virtualbox/configuration.html and https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html (search for --nictype) the following worked for me. I did not need to set KVM explicitely, because I was on Linux and it was the default.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"
    config.vm.hostname = "whatever"

    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.memory = "512"
        vb.cpus = "2"
        vb.default_nic_type = "virtio"
    end
end
```

By setting this default_nic_type to virtio, not only the first NAT-ed NIC got this type, but also I defined a second NIC (not shown here) and it also got created as virtio (virtio-net in virtualbox settings GUI).