# Vagrant - paravirtualization "kvm" on VirtualBox version below 5.0

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, kvm, paravirtualization

I have this vagrant settings below:

```
 12     config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
 13       v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "256"]
 14       v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "1"]
 15       v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--paravirtprovider", "kvm"]     #this should only be applied to LINUX guests
 16     end
```

Found this on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31410002/setting-paravirtualization-interface-in-vagrantfile).

Case is, if VirtualBox version is >= 5.0, this will definitely should work.
But on versions below 5.0, error should be raised.

Question: How am I able to check if `--paravirtprovider` is enabled in a VirtualBox version. If possible, I want this be done in the Vagrantfile itself. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be better ways to do this, but one way is:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
vbox_version = `VBoxManage --version`

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = 'ubuntu/trusty64'
  config.vm.provider 'virtualbox' do |v|
    v.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--memory', '256']
    v.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--cpus', '1']
    if vbox_version.to_f >= 5.0
      v.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--paravirtprovider', 'kvm']
    end
  end
end
```

`vbox_version =` `` `VBoxManage --version` `` has to happen outside of the configure block because it needs to be executed on the host system running vagrant and VirtualBox.

Comment: Works like charm! Thank you, thank you! Exactly what I am looking for! :)